# Typing website layout not working with different elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I and a friend are running into a lot of trouble trying to make a typing website.
When it starts, the HTML is like so.

```html
<div class="future">an arrow is a reinss brunt the reins of a falls becomes an awake rodeo peters are keyed snacks the ankle of a daddy becomes a joint bingo! of course the scrum of a nylon becomes a liver basis a jenny sees a setup as a prank fraud however daddy is a piles the mango of a heath becomes a widen lowry! in modern times snacks are footy brunts in ancient times the taker of a maam becomes a joint maam the first mixed heath is in its own way a squid a drank is a movers miner! `</div>
```

And that looks like:
[image]

When the user types something, it makes a portion of the text white, like this:

```html
<div class="future"><div style="color:white">an owner is </div><div>a barons bases by the waya rocks is the basis of a hello! a mirth is a vinyl skate the first razed reins is in its own way a metre of course a drank sees a snack as a footy snark a nexus is the gusto of a chili we know that a scrum is the mayer of a baker! metres are trunk barons; the trout is a jones ardors are eaten banjos! a villa is a quick manga we know that a mayer is a widen cabal their begun was in this moment a fated width`</div></div>
```

But it comes out like this:
[image]
Why does this happen? it should only change the color and not move everything.
We have checked the CSS multiple times, and can't figure out why this is happening.

All the best,
vibetype.

Comment: Why do you use `div`s instead of `span`s?

Comment: A div is a block level element and will create a return in the content. Depending on the styling of that parent, future, you are seeing the two block level elements line up next to each other.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion _"Don't include links except to support what you've written."_

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `div`s are block elements by default. You can use `span`s instead of `div`s. `span`s are inline elements by default. You could also change the `display` property but it's probably better to use the appropriate element. A `span` is the usual text element.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="future"><span style="color:white">an owner is </span><span>a barons bases by the waya rocks is the basis of a hello! a mirth is a vinyl skate the first razed reins is in its own way a metre of course a drank sees a snack as a footy snark a nexus is the gusto of a chili we know that a scrum is the mayer of a baker! metres are trunk barons; the trout is a jones ardors are eaten banjos! a villa is a quick manga we know that a mayer is a widen cabal their begun was in this moment a fated width`</span></div>
```